# Semantic UI React: How to make Tab menu use full width of container?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a component that uses Semantic UI `Tab` with only two (2) menu options.
My problem is, how to wrap the 2 options to take advantage of the full width of its container.

Kindly see picture below for reference:

[image]

I want "Calendar" and "To-Do List" use 50% each of the width.

I use the code in their sample as below:

```
      const panes = [{
                menuItem: 'Calendar',
                render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}><EventList /></Tab.Pane>
              },
              {
                menuItem: 'To-Do List',
                render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>Tab 2 Content</Tab.Pane>
              }
            ]
      return <Tab
          menu={{ attached: false }}
          panes={panes}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the number of panes in menu widths.

```
<Tab menu={{ widths: panes.length}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think the width of a tab is depends on content of each tab So I use 'Step' instead. Use this as Tab menu cuz it easier to make it equal.  https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/step/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZkNV.png)